# DataMaps / hide arcs by identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, datamaps

I've created a world map, using [DataMaps](http://datamaps.github.io/).

My aim is to asynchronously show and hide arcs on the map, based on some API data.

---

**What have I already tried**

I am calling my `API` every 5 seconds and push the response data into the map.
*(This will be replaced by asynchronous calls in the future)*

In my example below, the `arcData array` represents my `API` response.

I am able to access the arcs via `DOM manipulation`.
In my case I am using `d3.selectAll('path.datamaps-arc').transition().duration(3500).style("opacity", 0);` to slowly fade out all arcs and delete them afterwards.

```js
var arcData = //Test Data
[
  {
    origin: 
    {
          latitude: 52.520008,
          longitude: 13.404954
    },
    destination: {
          latitude: 37.618889,
          longitude: -122.375
    }
 },
 {   origin: 
    {
          latitude: 52.520008,
          longitude: 13.404954
    },
    destination: {
          latitude: 25.793333,
          longitude:-80.290556
    }
 },
 {
    origin: 
    {
          latitude: 52.520008,
          longitude: 13.404954
    },
    destination: {
          latitude: 35.877778,
          longitude: -78.7875
    }
 }
];


$(document).ready(function() {
  var map = new Datamap({ //create data map
    element: document.getElementById('container'),
    fills: {
      defaultFill: "#343a40",
    }
  });
  
  //call API every 4 seconds [Workaround for this fiddle]  
  setInterval(function() {
    //add arcs to map
    map.arc(arcData, {strokeWidth: 2, animationSpeed: 1000, strokeColor: '#b1dd00'}); // add arc Data

    //Remove all arcs [should be replaced by a function that asynchronously hides single arcs after x seconds]
    d3.selectAll('path.datamaps-arc').transition().duration(3500).style("opacity", 0);
    d3.selectAll('path.datamaps-arc').transition().delay(3500).remove();
  }, 4000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/topojson/1.6.9/topojson.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://datamaps.github.io/scripts/datamaps.world.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="position: relative; width: 500px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

---

This solution basically works but:

**My Problem**

All arcs are hided at the same time. 
If i asynchronously call the API in the future, there will be a conflict when the arc is currently drawing, and meanwhile the delete process is triggered.

**What I want**

A solution that I can access every arc by some identifier and separately delete them after they are fully drawed.

Comment: Do you want to identify arc by it's latitude longitude?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All arcs added via [DataMaps](http://datamaps.github.io/) are actually keyed by their `data` in JSON format ([datamaps.js#L356](https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps/blob/e11c513a23e1a7b836fee0605d478dc9ca176151/src/js/datamaps.js#L356)):

```
var arcs = layer.selectAll('path.datamaps-arc').data( data, JSON.stringify );
```

Notice that [DataMaps](http://datamaps.github.io/) use `JSON.stringify` as **key function**. *It would be nice if DataMaps provide a way to use custom key function here, but alas...*

While these keys themselves are not persisted, it is enough to ensure us that there would only be one arc for one identical data. The arc data is the arc identifier itself.

Using these knowledge, we can identify an arc by comparing it's data:

```
var selectedArcs = d3.selectAll('path.datamaps-arc').filter(function(data) {
   // compare data
   return data === someValue;
});
```

To take it further, we can actually tweak the data we pass to `DataMaps.arc` so that it will actually holds our compare-friendly identifier. The `origin` and `destination` field is mandatory, but we're free to use any other field to our liking.

```
{
  id: 'some-unique-identifier',
  origin: {
    latitude: 52.520008,
    longitude: 13.404954
  },
  destination: {
    latitude: 37.618889,
    longitude: -122.375
  }
}
```

We could then use this tweaked field(s) for identifying our arc:

```
var selectedArcs = d3.selectAll('path.datamaps-arc').filter(function(data) {
   return data.id === 'some-unique-identifier';
});
```

> Keep in minds that [DataMaps](http://datamaps.github.io/) keyed each of our arc using its whole `data` value; meaning that two data with same `id` but different `origin` and or `destination` value would be considered two different arc.

Here's a simple demonstration using a modified version of the original example:

```js
var arcData = //Test Data
[
  {
    id: 123,
    origin: 
    {
          latitude: 52.520008,
          longitude: 13.404954
    },
    destination: {
          latitude: 37.618889,
          longitude: -122.375
    }
 },
  { 
   id: 'abc',
    origin: 
    {
          latitude: 52.520008,
          longitude: 13.404954
    },
    destination: {
          latitude: 25.793333,
          longitude:-80.290556
    }
 },
  {
    id: 'xyz',
    origin: 
    {
          latitude: 52.520008,
          longitude: 13.404954
    },
    destination: {
          latitude: 35.877778,
          longitude: -78.7875
    }
 }
];


$(document).ready(function() {
  var map = new Datamap({ //create data map
    element: document.getElementById('container'),
    fills: {
      defaultFill: "#343a40",
    }
  });
  
  function drawMap() {
    map.arc(arcData, {strokeWidth: 2, animationSpeed: 1000, strokeColor: '#b1dd00'});
  };
  
  function removeArc(id) {  
    var all = d3.selectAll('path.datamaps-arc');
    var sel = all.filter(function(data) {
      return data.id === id;
    });
    sel.transition().duration(1000).style("opacity", 0).remove();
  };
  
  $('button').on('click', function(){ 
    var id = $(this).data('arc');
    if (id) {
      removeArc(id);
    } else {
      drawMap();
    }
  });
  
  drawMap();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/topojson/1.6.9/topojson.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://datamaps.github.io/scripts/datamaps.world.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" data-arc="123">Remove Arc id:123</button>
<button type="button" data-arc="abc">Remove Arc id:abc</button>
<button type="button" data-arc="xyz">Remove Arc id:xyz</button>
<button type="button">Redraw</button>
<div id="container" style="position: relative; width: 500px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

Comment: Very nice, I love the Idea to assign id's in the API response itself and identify them by their assigned id. I will run some tests first but It looks like this is what i wanted.

Comment: @IronGeek +1 I like the way as well, I was looking for it from yesterday but not able to find it. You deserves the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

Well I have tried to solve your problem. What I have did is, I have assigned unique ids to each arc of data-map. It will easily give you access to independent arcs and you can change their transitions accordingly.

For demo purpose I have delayed it randomly and it works properly. I have delayed first arc by 1000 ms second arc by 2000 ms and third arc by 3000 ms. You can implement your own algorithm to delay the arcs' transitions as you wish. I have added comments in the code which you can refer.

As setInterval is running after every 4000 ms, if delay of any arc is more than 4000 ms then you will be able to see all the arcs generating at the same time only once which is the first time. After that generation of arcs will be very random, so please just keep it in mind.

```js
var arcData = //Test Data
                [{
                        origin: {
                            latitude: 52.520008,
                            longitude: 13.404954
                        },
                        destination: {
                            latitude: 37.618889,
                            longitude: -122.375
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        origin: {
                            latitude: 52.520008,
                            longitude: 13.404954
                        },
                        destination: {
                            latitude: 25.793333,
                            longitude: -80.290556
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        origin: {
                            latitude: 52.520008,
                            longitude: 13.404954
                        },
                        destination: {
                            latitude: 35.877778,
                            longitude: -78.7875
                        }
                    }
                ];


            $(document).ready(function() {
                var map = new Datamap({ //create data map
                    element: document.getElementById('container'),
                    fills: {
                        defaultFill: "#343a40",
                    }
                });
                //hide arc function which will take x amount of delay and arc-id which you want to delay.
                function hideArc(delay, arcId) {
                    d3.select('#' + arcId).transition().duration(delay).style("opacity", 0);
                    d3.select('#' + arcId).transition().delay(delay).remove();
                }

                //call API every 4 seconds [Workaround for this fiddle]  
                setInterval(function() {
                    //add arcs to map
                    map.arc(arcData, {
                        strokeWidth: 2,
                        animationSpeed: 1000,
                        strokeColor: '#b1dd00'
                    }); // add arc Data
                    let arcIds = [];// it will hold all the unique arc-ids
                    d3.selectAll('path.datamaps-arc')[0].forEach((ele, index) => {
                        ele.setAttribute('id', 'datamap-arc-' + index);
                        arcIds.push('datamap-arc-' + index);// pushing new generated ids to arcIds array
                    });
                    //mapping of delay and arc-id, this part is replaceable, you can change it the way you want to change the delay of respective arc.   
                    let arcIdAndDelaymapping = arcIds.map((aercId, index) => {
                        return {
                            aercId,
                            delay:1000*(index+1)
                        }
                    })


                    //Remove all arcs [should be replaced by a function that asynchronously hides single arcs after x seconds]
                    //calling hideArc function with their respective delays.  
                    arcIdAndDelaymapping.forEach((arcMapping) => {
                        hideArc(arcMapping.delay, arcMapping.aercId);
                    })
                }, 4000);
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/topojson/1.6.9/topojson.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://datamaps.github.io/scripts/datamaps.world.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="position: relative; width: 500px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

Hopefully it will solve your problem. Happy Coding!! And thanks for making me explore data-maps.

Comment: Thanks,
this is a very interresting way of identify arcs by assign unique id's to them.
I've tested different ways of it and tried to implement. It improves my map but i still have problems when i get responses from different Webservices because the id's array will be overwritten every time. However, votes up.

Comment: @toffler I can understand the problem, that's why I asked the question. And I think IronGeek's answer will solve your problem. He deserves the bounty. :)